# How to get correct min, max date for each customer's changing label in wide format in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I have a table that records customer purchases, for example:

| customer_id | label | date | purchase_id | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | A | 2022-01-01 | asd | 10 |
| 3 | A | 2022-01-01 | asdf | 5 |
| 4 | B | 2022-02-04 | asdfg | 200 |
| 2 | A | 2022-01-03 | asdjg | 4 |
| 3 | B | 2022-02-01 | dfs | 20 |
| 2 | G | 2022-04-05 | fdg | 40 |
| 2 | G | 2022-04-10 | fdg | 40 |
| 2 | A | 2022-06-06 | fgd | 20 |

I want to see how many days/money each customer has spent in each label, so far what I'm doing is:

```
SELECT
customer_id,
label,
COUNT(DISTINCT(purchase_id) as orders_count,
SUM(price) as total_spent,
min(date) as first_date,
max(date) as last_date,
DATE_DIFF(max(date), min(date), DAY) as days
FROM
TABLE
WHERE
date > '2022-01-01'
GROUP BY
customer_id,
label
```

which gives me a long table, like this:

| customer_id | label | orders_count | total_spent | first_date | last_date | days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | A | 3 | 34 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-06-06 | 180 |
| 2 | G | 1 | 40 | 2022-04-05 | 2022-04-10 | 5 |

etc

Just for simplicity I show a few columns, but customers have orders all the time. The issue with the above is that, for example for customer `2`, that he starts with label A, then changes to G, then he is back to A so this is not visible in the results table (min(date) is correct, but max(date) takes their 2nd A max(date)) and that I'd prefer to have it in wide format. For instance, ideally, columns called next_label_{i} that you get values for each changing label would be the best for me.

Could you advise me of a way of a) dealing with accomodating with this label change(future label change is the same as an earlier label) and b) a way to produce it into a wide format?

Thanks

edit:
example output (correct date, wide format) [columns would go as wide as the max number of unique labels for any customer]

| customer_id | first_label | first_first_date | first_last_date | first_total_spent | first_days | next_label | next_first_date | next_last_date | next_days | next_label_2 | next_first_date_2 | next_last_date_2 | next_days_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | A | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-03 | 2 | 14 | G | 2022-04-05 | 2022-04-05 | 0 | A | 2022-06-06 | 2022-06-06 | 0 |

etc

Sorry this is not exactly accurate (missing the orders_count, total_spent) but it's a pain in the ass for format it here, but hopefully you get the idea. In principle, it's something as if you used python's pivot_table on the previous dataset.

Alternatively, I'd be glad for just a solution in the long format that distinguishes between a customer's label and the same customer's repeated label ( as in customer 2 who starts with A and after changing to G, returns to A)

Comment: Can you add an example output of what you're expecting

Comment: hey just edited my reply but I can't make the table look good. Hope you get what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2):

> Could you advise me of ... b) a way to produce it into a wide format?

First, I want to say that I hope you have really good reason to get that output as usually it is not what is considered a best practices and rather is being left for presentation layer to handle.

With that in mind  - consider below approach

```
select * from (
  select customer_id, offset, purchase.*
  from (
    select customer_id, 
      array_agg((struct(label, date, purchase_id, price)) order by date) purchases
    from your_table 
    group by customer_id
  ), unnest(purchases) purchase with offset
  order by customer_id, offset
)
pivot (
  any_value(label) label, 
  any_value(date) date, 
  any_value(purchase_id) purchase_id, 
  any_value(price) price
  for offset in (0,1,2,3,4,5)
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Note: *Above has silly assumption that you know the max number of steps (in this case I used 6 - from 0 till 5). There are plenty of posts here on SO that shows how to use same technique to make it dynamic. I do not want to duplicate them as it is against SO policies. So, just do your extra homework on this :o)*

Comment: thanks for the reply, I'll look more into this - I can get the data off bq and do the above dynamically in pandas but I'm not that experienced in sql stuff. Do you have any input for the other part of my question? The one about having the correct dates when a customer changes from label A to B and then to A again? Not sure if that is even possible

Comment: Is maybe the solution to use a counter for each switch, so I can groupby label and counter? That's how I would do it in python I guess

Comment: it is hard to answer post with multiple questions in it. if this would work for you - i recommend to dedicate this post to wide output question. and for another part  - you would post separate question/post and we (for sure I will) will be happy to help further :o)

Comment: Thanks, I marked your reply as the answer and have made another post for the other part if you're still interested

Comment: Actually I only just had a closer look at your answer and it's not exactly what I was looking for, since it widens the data per any label entry and not groupedby the labels, but maybe I can work it out